# Jenkins Automation to push tarball into artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I want to create tarball for npm build from jenkins (angular 2 project) and publish into artifactory . I have used artifactory plugin and it pushed code into Jfrog builds but not in artifactory.

How to publish tarball to artifactory from jenkins for npm project , solutions I am getting are for maven ,gradle and ivy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Artifactory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) to do this.

Configure you artiactory server in the manager jenkins area properly.

You will need to ticket Generic-Artifactory Integration in your job.
Then enter a file spec:

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "Build\build.tar",
            "target": "REPO name",
            "props": "test=banana"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then your tar will be pushed to artifactory.

Comment: I did this it pushed into build and not artifacts

Comment: @devinenisakethsai Yes this is because it's a build of the software, i believe that you can have a release build push to a different repository, I haven't done this yet however.